# Knapsack with multiple contstraits

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

Given problem:

n items, each having a `value val`, a `weight w`, and an `volume vol`. Basically the same as knapsack 0/1 problem however the task is to find the **maximum value V** you can get in the knapsack **but the weight can't be more than W_max and also the volume needs to be at least Vol_min**.

The value, weight and volume are given in three arrays:

```
val[n+1], w[n+1], vol[n+1]
The i-th item has value val[i], weight w[i] and volume vol[i]
```

I know how to solve the normal 0/1 knapsack problem with only one limit but I'm not sure how to solve this one. I was thinking of using a 3D DP table but how is an entry in the table defined?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
static int knapsack(int[] vol, int[] w, int[] val, int n, int Vol_min, int W_max) {

    int[][][] DP = new int[n+1][W_max][Vol_min];

    for(int i = 1; i < n+1; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < W_max; j++) {
            for(int k = 0; k < Vol_min; k++) {

                if(w[i] > W_max) {
                    DP[i][j][k] = DP[i-1][j][k];
                } else {

                    if(j - w[i] >= 0 && k + vol[i] <= n) {
                        DP[i][j][k] = Math.max(DP[i-1][j][k], DP[i-1][j - w[i]][k + vol[i]] + val[i]);
                    } else {
                        DP[i][j][k] = DP[i-1][j][k];
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    return DP[n][n][n]; 
}
```

Here is an example of the problem:

```
n = 6, Vol_min = 10, W_max = 12
vol = {1, 3, 7, 5, 1, 3}, w = {4, 5, 10, 2, 1, 4}, val = {10, 8, 5, 3, 1, 2}
=> Result: 22
```

Comment: `dp[i][j][k] = max(dp[i-1][j][k],dp[i-1][j-w[i]][k-vol[i]]+val[i])` - ???

Comment: @ShihabShahriar I think that would be the solution if the maximum volume is an upper bound, but here the volume is minimum, i.e. a lower bound.

Comment: You should be able to let the third dimension instead represent the maximum for a given volume as opposed to across all volumes as you have right now. Is this a competition problem? Could you share the link to the problem? I'm fairly certain this can be done however I could be a little more concrete with the idea if there's a place I can get a judge result from.

Comment: @kevmo314 I added a simple example, unfortunately I can't give you the link to the judge as it's limited for certain users...

Comment: @G.M Have you considered using recursive DP?

Comment: @WIR3D what do you mean exactly with "recursive" DP?

Comment: Recursive DP is a kind of DP that uses recursion while memoising the results of previous calculations.

Comment: @WIR3D hmm... ok, yeah, I've never really heard of that before and thus never used it, so I don't know how I would use this...

Comment: I'm posting a solution gimmie one sec

Answer (score 2):

So using recursive DP, I came up with a pretty standard solution for 1/0 Knapsack with a slight modification.

```
    public static int[][] dp;// Item number, Weight, Volume
    public static int[] vol, w, val;
    public static int Vol_min, W_max, n;

    static int knapsack(int item, int weight, int volume) {
        // See if we have calculated this item before
        if (dp[item][weight] == -1) {
            // Set initial value to -2 (invalid result)
            int max = -2;
            // Iterate though all items past current item
            for (int i = item; i < n; i++) {
                // Make sure we don't go over max weight
                if (weight + w[i] <= W_max) {
                    // Get the result of taking ith item
                    int res = knapsack(i + 1, weight + w[i], volume + vol[i]);
                    // Make sure result is valid (Total volume is greater than
                    // Vol_min)
                    if (res != -2) {
                        // If the result is valid take the max
                        max = Math.max(res + val[i], max);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (max == -2 && volume >= Vol_min)// No other items taken and over
                                                // Vol_min
                dp[item][weight] = 0;
            else // Eveything else
                dp[item][weight] = max;
        }
        // Return the value
        return dp[item][weight];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        n = 6;
        Vol_min = 10;
        W_max = 12;
        vol = new int[] { 1, 3, 7, 5, 1, 3 };
        w = new int[] { 4, 5, 10, 2, 1, 4 };
        val = new int[] { 10, 8, 5, 3, 1, 2 };
        dp = new int[n + 1][W_max + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= W_max; j++) {
                dp[i][j] = -1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(knapsack(0, 0, 0));

    }
```

So imagine that we had a magical function `knapsack(item,weight,volume)` that could return the largest valid value of items that could be taken given the item number, weight and volume.

The solution would then iterate though every item after it and see what the answer would be and take the largest one. Similar to the 1/0 DP that you do. However, you realize that you don't need to keep track of the volume in the dp array hence it being only 2D. You only need to keep track of the volume at the end when you see that there are no more items that can be taken. Then you check to see if the solution is valid.